# iOS 13 Burp Suite Proxy Unable to Connect

Tags: proxy, charles-proxy, burp

I am trying to run Burp Suite proxy to do some testing from my phone.

I have setup Burp Suite Community Edition 2.1.04
I have set my wifi to use my computer's IP address as the proxy on the correct port in *Proxy* > *Options* > *Proxy Listeners*.

[image]

From my iOS device I used Safari and went to http://{ComputerIP}:{Port} and installed the CA Cert.
I installed the Cert from Settings. I also trusted the cert in About > Cert Trust Settings.

[image]

I can't get out to the internet on my phone. I can see in the Burp Suite HTTP History that a connection to Google was made but the connection was closed. I tried http://example.com and still couldn't get out.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Cookie: REALLY LONG COOKIE STRING
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
```

I have followed [this](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1841109-Mobile%20Set-up_iOS%20Device%20-%20Installing%20CA%20Certificate.html) and [this](https://medium.com/@srits.ashish/how-to-configure-burp-suite-on-iphone-or-network-logs-of-ios-app-using-burp-suite-for-mac-58b0cf97e85d) tutorial, but no luck.

Any thoughts?

I tried Charles Proxy, but I need TLS 1.3.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should wait for Port Swigger certificate update. 
There are new requirements in iOS 13 for TLS - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176

As alternative you can use https://proxyman.io/ with macOS. This should work with iOS13

Answer (score 1):

I just set up Burp in ios 15 device.
After installing Burp certificate from Settings -> Profile in my Iphone, SSL still wasn't working for me.
However, i had to also go to Settings -> Trusted Certificates -> Certificate Trust Settings and toggle the PortSwigger Certificate.

I also had to go to Burp -> Proxy > Options > Edit proxy listener you are using -> Edit proxy Listener -> TLS Protocols. Use custom protocols and deselect TLSv1.1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1. I only selected TLSv1.3

Afterwards, SSL worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me, and should be on the top.

Answer (score 0):

For Burp on iOS 13 the provided certificate by the proxy does not work, I had generated my own doing the following...

Make a new folder:

```
 mkdir BurpCA && cd BurpCA
```

Create *BurpCA.cnf* file with this content:

```
[ req ]
default_md              = sha256
distinguished_name      = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions         = root_ca

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName             = US
countryName_min         = 2
countryName_max         = 2
stateOrProvinceName     = California
localityName            = Los Angeles
0.organizationName      = ROTTEN APPLE
organizationalUnitName  = ROTTEN APPLE
commonName              = localhost
commonName_max          = 64
emailAddress            = admin@localhost
emailAddress_max        = 64

[ root_ca ]
nsComment               = "Certificate for Burp"
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
basicConstraints        = critical, CA:true
keyUsage                = critical, keyCertSign
```

Run

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -out BurpCA.cer -outform PEM -keyout BurpCA.key -days 720 -verbose -config BurpCA.cnf -nodes -sha256 -subj "/CN=ROTTEN APPLE CA"
```

Prepare the certificate to import it to Burp and set export password as "burp"

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out Burp.pfx -inkey BurpCA.key -in BurpCA.cer
```

Open Burp (make sure to update to the latest version)

Go to:

- Proxy Tab
- Options
- Import / Export CA Certificate
- Certificate and private key in PKCS#12 format

Then on your iPhone set the proxy go to http://burp and follow the proper installation.

Comment: Since ios 13.5.1 This method is no longer working :(

Answer (score 0):

Got this working finally!

Here are the full instructions:

1. Generate a certificate with the following commands:
   openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout myBurpCA.key -out root-ca.crt -days 365 -subj "/C=CA/O=Burp/OU=Certification Services/CN=MyBURPRootCA/" -addext "extendedKeyUsage=1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1"
   openssl pkcs12 -export -out BurpRootCA.pfx -inkey myBurpCA.key -in root-ca.crt
2. Go to burp and use the "Import / Export CA certificate" option and select your newly generated certificate (use the pfx file).
   **DO NOT** use "Edit Proxy Listener -> Certificate -> Use a custom certificate". It will not work (this is a custom specific certificate, you still want a CA-signed per-host certificate).
3. Go to the iPhone, configure the Burp Suite proxy as the proxy server and go to http://burp
4. Download and install the certificate by click the top right corner, downloading it ("Allow") and then going to settings -> Profile Downloaded -> Install, to finish the additional installation steps.
5. Authorize the installed certificate for TLS authentication by going to Settings > General > About > Certificate Trust Settings, and then toggle "Enable Full Trust for Root Certificates" on for the certificate.

That's it! Certificate is now valid for TLS authentication.

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky to manually generate a self-signed certifciate that comply with new [Apple Security Update](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176) from iOS 13 and Catalina. Here is the simple one:

1. Prepare cert.config file on Desktop folder

```sh
[ ca ]
default_ca    = CA_default
[ CA_default ]
default_md    = sha256
[ v3_ca ]
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer
basicConstraints = critical,CA:true
keyUsage=critical,keyCertSign
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth,clientAuth
[ req ]
prompt = no
distinguished_name    = req_distinguished_name
[ req_distinguished_name ]
C=SG
L=SG
O=Proxyman
CN=proxyman.dev
OU=Proxyman
```

Please update values for C, L, O, CN, and OU param.

2. Generate RSA Key in the Terminal app. (Make sure you replace your_password to your real password)

```
cd ~/Desktop
openssl genrsa -aes256 -passout pass:your_password -out key.pem 2048
```

3. Generate the self-signed certificate and private key. (Make sure you replace your_password to your real password)

```sh
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -passin pass:your_password -config cert.config -key key.pem -sha256 -extensions v3_ca -days 825 -out root-ca.pem
```

4. Convert to p12 format. (Make sure you replace your_password to your real password)

```sh
openssl pkcs12 -export -out root-ca.p12 -in root-ca.pem -inkey key.pem -passin pass:your_password -passout pass:your_password
```

5. Finally, you would have root-ca.p12 file.

---

If you're looking for an easier way to do it, let check out Proxyman with [Custom Root Certificate feature](https://docs.proxyman.io/advanced-features/custom-certificates#6-how-to-generate-self-signed-certificates-for-custom-root-certificate-that-comply-with-new-apples-security-requirements). It possible to use it on iOS and Android remote devices.

[image: Custom Root Certificate]

Disclaimer: I write Proxyman app. Hopefully it helps anyone who struggle with SSL stuff.